# No F# generics with constant "template arguments"?

Tags: f#

It just occurred to me, that F# generics do not seem to accept constant values as "template parameters".

Suppose one wanted to create a type `RangedInt` such, that it behaves like an int but is guaranteed to only contain a sub-range of integer values.

A possible approach could be a discriminated union, similar to:

```
type RangedInt = | Valid of int | Invalid
```

But this is not working either, as there is no "type specific storage of the range information". And 2 RangedInt instances should be of different type, if the range differs, too.

Being still a bit C++ infested it would look similar to:

```
template<int low,int high>
class RangedInteger { ... };
```

Now the question, arising is two fold:

1. Did I miss something and constant values for F# generics exist?
2. If I did not miss that, what would be the idiomatic way to accomplish such a `RangedInt<int,int>` in F#?

Having found [Tomas Petricek's blog about custom numeric types](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/), the equivalent to my question for that blog article would be: What if he did not an `IntegerZ5` but an `IntegerZn<int>` custom type family?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The language feature you're requesting is called [Dependent Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), and F# doesn't have that feature.

It's not a particularly common language feature, and even Haskell (which most other Functional programming languages 'look up to') doesn't really have it.

There *are* languages with Dependent Types out there, but none of them I would consider mainstream. Probably the one I hear about the most is [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org).

Comment: In fact, I spent a while yesterday on Dependent types and found a ML-mutation named ATS (could not get it running, though). The idea of it is to have a language combining logic programming and solvers at compile time so people can write proofs for their code - those being removed at compile time after verifying the code with it. My F# idea was basically: How far can I go that direction using a modern mainstream language?

Answer (score 1):

> Did I miss something and constant values for F# generics exist?

While F# has much strong type inference than other .NET languages, at its heart it is built on .NET.

And .NET generics only support a small subset of what is possible with C++ templates. All type arguments to generic types must be types, and there is no defaulting of type arguments either.

> If I did not miss that, what would be the idiomatic way to accomplish such a RangedInt in F#?

It would depend on the details. Setting the limits at runtime is one possibility – this would be the usual approach in .NET. Another would be units of measure (this seems less likely to be a fit).

> What if he did not an `IntegerZ5` but an `IntegerZn<int>` custom type family?

I see two reasons:

- It is an example, and avoiding generics keeps things simpler allowing focus on the point of the example.
- What other underlying type would one use anyway? On contemporary systems smaller types (`byte`, `Int16` etc.) are less efficient (unless space at runtime is the overwhelming concern); `long` would add size without benefit (it is only going to hold 5 possible values).

Comment: Yes, and keeping away from generics also kept the article away from the problem in my question :) In other words, the ``IntegerZn<int>`` was meant in the sense of ``IntegerZn<5>``, not in the "which base-type to use" kind of sense.

Comment: And setting values at runtime is not an option as what I try to achieve is to have the type system catch bugs at compile time. If it was 1 type with range settings, it would still be but 1 type.